# iterating over QPushButtons and changing background color using "setStyleSheet" for each

Tags: python, loops, pyqt

I have buttons set up in a layout grid. After performing  an operation, I'll place the coordinates of select widgets in a queue. The program then performs a while loop, and inside the loop I pop from the queue, and perform `setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")` until there are no elements left in the queue.

My issue is that `setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")` performs after the loop has finished, and thusly all the buttons are colored at once. I would like for them to be colored sequentially after about a second or so. I've tried implementing the timer, but the buttons still color

These are the pieces of codes I seem to be having problems with:

```
def set_style(gridElem):
    gridElem.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")
    print("set color")

def start_search():
    s.iterative()

    while(s.fifo):
        print(s.fifo)
        cell = s.fifo.popleft()
        print(cell[0])
        gridElem = grid.itemAtPosition(cell[0], cell[1])
        if gridElem != None:
            set_style(gridElem.widget())
```

Comment: Supposing that reading that fifo requires a considerable but still reasonable amount of time (more than 2-3ms at least), you could just call `QApplication.processEvents()`. If the time is more and/or unpredictable, then consider using QThread and connect to a function that updates the stylesheets (you cannot do that directly from the thread, as widgets are not thread safe).

Comment: @musicamante Thanks ```QApplicatoin.processEvents()``` seemed to work